# Caracteres Especiais - SQL

Tags: sql, caracteres

Alguem sabe como eu consigo filtrar apenas caracteres como no exemplo abaixo ?

```
Email
JhónSnow@gmail.com
Khãlessi@gmail.com
```

Como visto acima aparece '´' e '~' , além disso podem aparecer '..' ou ',' e gostaria de filtrar isso . Tem como criar um padrão para isso ?

Queria arranjar um jeito de pegar qualquer tipo de caracter especial tanto como acentuação como %,#, ou outros desse tipo

Estou usando o Sql Server 2012

Comment: Como assim "filtrar"? Você quer fazer uma busca dos e-mails que possuem esses caracteres?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss , então a busca que eu preciso fazer além de todas as informações que possuem acentuação , também aquelas que possuem algum .. ou , , emfim o que não apresentar algum caracter especial

Comment: Mais confuso ainda... "o que não apresentar algum caracter especial", você quer que o resultado seja os que CONTÉM esses caracteres ou que NÃO CONTÉM?

Comment: Quero que o resultado contenha esses caracteres

Answer (score 3):

A seguinte consulta irá trazer toda a linha que contém qualquer caracter especial.

```
Select * from tabela Where Coluna LIKE '%[^A-Za-z0-9, ]%'
```

Você também pode tentar um where com todos os caracteres, é mais trabalhoso e claro, você precisa conhecer todos os caracteres:

```
Coluna LIKE '[!@#$%]'
```